# I am using python to blend to images by fading one over other but I am getting black bg or pixels after fading

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, scikit-learn, python-imaging-library

I am trying to add banner to festival posts by using python.
-> added successfully
-> but there is clear border bw banner and input image so I decided to fade the downside of banner
->After adding -> real issue encounters in which I am getting black background or black pixels after fading but I want background of input image or pixels of input image to do proper merging of banner and input image

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import cv2
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

def calculate_main_color(image_path):
    # Load the image and convert it to a NumPy array
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)  # Convert to RGB color space
    image = image.reshape((-1, 3))  # Reshape to a 2D array of RGB values

    # Perform K-Means clustering to find the dominant color
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=1)
    kmeans.fit(image)
    dominant_color = kmeans.cluster_centers_[0].astype(int)

    return tuple(dominant_color)

def fade_banner(image_data, fade_height=15):
    height, width, _ = image_data.shape
    for y in range(height - fade_height, height):
        alpha = 1.0 - (y - (height - fade_height)) / fade_height
        image_data[y, :, 0:3] = (image_data[y, :, 0:3] * alpha).astype(np.uint8)

def create_customized_image(festival_image_path, banner_image_path, result_image_path, upscale_factor=2, fade_height=15):
    # Load festival image
    festival_image = Image.open(festival_image_path)

    # Load banner image
    banner_image = Image.open(banner_image_path)

    # Calculate the main color of the festival image
    main_color = calculate_main_color(festival_image_path)

    # Get the size of the festival image
    festival_width, festival_height = festival_image.size

    # Resize the banner image to fit within the dimensions of the festival image
    banner_image.thumbnail((festival_width, festival_height))

    # Get the size of the resized banner image
    banner_width, banner_height = banner_image.size

    # Create a gradient banner to match the festival image width
    gradient = np.linspace(0, 1, festival_width).reshape(festival_width, 1, 1)
    banner_data = np.array(banner_image)

    # Remove the alpha channel from banner_data
    banner_data = banner_data[:, :, :3]

    # Adjust the banner's color to match the main color
    for channel in range(3):  # Loop through RGB channels
        adjusted_channel = (banner_data[:, :, channel].astype(float) * (main_color[channel] / 255)).astype(np.uint8)
        banner_data[:, :, channel] = adjusted_channel

    # Apply the fade effect to the bottom of the banner
    fade_banner(banner_data, fade_height)

    # Convert the festival image to a NumPy array
    festival_data = np.array(festival_image)

    # Blend the festival image and the banner image after the fade effect
    result_image_data = np.copy(festival_data)

    # Apply the banner on top of the festival image
    result_image_data[:banner_height] = banner_data



    # Upscale the resulting image for higher quality
    result_image_data = cv2.resize(result_image_data, None, fx=upscale_factor, fy=upscale_factor, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

    # Create an Image object from the modified numpy array
    result_image = Image.fromarray(result_image_data)

    # Save the resulting image
    result_image.save(result_image_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Specify the paths to your input image, banner image, and the output image
    input_image_path = "/Users/shameerali/Desktop/inputFolder/input_image.jpg"
    banner_image_path = "/Users/shameerali/Desktop/inputFolder/banner_image.png"
    output_image_path = "/Users/shameerali/Desktop/inputFolder/output_image.jpg"

    create_customized_image(input_image_path, banner_image_path, output_image_path)
```

this is my banner image[image]

this is my input image [image]

I am getting this output image [image]

I am doing fade effect at the bottom of the banner for ensuring proper merging of images but I am getting black background after merging.

Comment: You get the dominant color but don't use it.  You create a gradient (with the dimension swapped) but do not use it.  You manually create a fade_banner which is inefficient, when you could just use OpenCV or Numpy to do the fade of a gradient.  What debugging have you done?  Have you looked at the result for each step to see if it is what you expect.  I think you are fading the banner to black but not fading oppositely the input_image and not blending the two.

Comment: I think what you should do is create a gradient image your desired size. Then crop your banner bottom and top of the image to the same size. Then use np.where(mask=gradient, banner, image) to blend them. The vertically concatenate the top of the banner, the blended result, and the bottom of the image.

Comment: it worked thnx for the suggestions